How can I have the outcome of the input values in a multiple form show in a dialog or modal as preview when submitted?
I am not trying to build a form in the dialog, I want the input values from the submitted form to show in a dialog/modal, sort of like a summary of the details field in the multi-form component (NextJS) Here is the code for the form component:
'use client'

// React Imports
import { useState } from 'react'

// MUI Imports
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
import Step from '@mui/material/Step'
import Select from '@mui/material/Select'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider'
import Stepper from '@mui/material/Stepper'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import StepLabel from '@mui/material/StepLabel'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel'
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent'
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl'
import FormHelperText from '@mui/material/FormHelperText'

// Third-party Imports
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { valibotResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/valibot'
import { email, object, minLength, string, array } from 'valibot'

// Component Imports
import StepperWrapper from '@core/styles/stepper'
import StepperCustomDot from './StepperCustomDot'
import PreviewModal from '@/components/dialogs/preview-user'



// Vars
const steps = [
  {
    title: 'User Details',
    subtitle: 'Enter user details'
  },
  {
    title: 'Personal Info',
    subtitle: 'Setup Information'
  }

]

const accountSchema = object(
  {
    username: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
    email: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required'), email()]),
    role: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
    branchCode: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')])
  })

const personalSchema = object({
  firstName: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
  lastName: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
  country: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
  language: array(string(), [minLength(1, 'This field is required')])
})

const socialSchema = object({
  twitter: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
  facebook: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
  google: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')]),
  linkedIn: string([minLength(1, 'This field is required')])
})

const StepperLinearWithValidation = () => {
  // States
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0)
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<any>(null)
  const [openPreviewModal, setOpenPreviewModal] = useState(false)


  // Vars
  const Languages = ['English', 'French', 'Spanish', 'Portuguese', 'Italian', 'German', 'Arabic']
  const roles = ['Administrator', 'Editor', 'Support', 'Users', 'Restricted User'] // Options for 'role' dropdown
  const branchCodes = ['Branch A', 'Branch B', 'Branch C'] // Options for 'branchCode' dropdown

  // Hooks
  const {
    reset: accountReset,
    control: accountControl,
    handleSubmit: handleAccountSubmit,
    formState: { errors: accountErrors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: valibotResolver(accountSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: '',
      email: '',
      role: '',
      branchCode: ''
    }
  })

  const {
    reset: personalReset,
    control: personalControl,
    handleSubmit: handlePersonalSubmit,
    formState: { errors: personalErrors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: valibotResolver(personalSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      country: '',
      language: []
    }
  })

  const {
    reset: socialReset,
    control: socialControl,
    handleSubmit: handleSocialSubmit,
    formState: { errors: socialErrors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: valibotResolver(socialSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      twitter: '',
      facebook: '',
      google: '',
      linkedIn: ''
    }
  })

  type AccountFormData = {
    username: string
    department: string
    role: string
    branchCode: string
  }

  type PersonalFormData = {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    country: string
    language: string[]
  }

  type FormData = {
    account: AccountFormData
    personal: PersonalFormData
  }

  const onSubmit = (formData: any) => {
    setFormData(formData)
    console.log('Form Data:', formData)
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1)

    if (activeStep === steps.length - 1) {
      toast.success('Form Submitted')
    }
  }

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep - 1)
  }

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0)
    accountReset({ email: '', username: '', role: '', branchCode: '' })
    personalReset({ firstName: '', lastName: '', country: '', language: [] })
    socialReset({ twitter: '', facebook: '', google: '', linkedIn: '' })
  }

  const renderStepContent = (activeStep: number) => {
    switch (activeStep) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <form key={0} onSubmit={handleAccountSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Grid container spacing={5}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography className='font-medium' color='text.primary'>
                  {steps[0].title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant='body2'>{steps[0].subtitle}</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='username'
                  control={accountControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      fullWidth
                      label='Username'
                      placeholder='johnDoe'
                      {...(accountErrors.username && { error: true, helperText: accountErrors.username.message })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='email'
                  control={accountControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      fullWidth
                      type='department'
                      label='Department'
                      placeholder='department name'
                      {...(accountErrors.email && { error: true, helperText: accountErrors.email.message })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel id='stepper-linear-validation-role-label'>Role</InputLabel>
                  <Controller
                    name='role'
                    control={accountControl}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <Select
                        {...field}
                        labelId='stepper-linear-validation-role-label'
                        label='Role'
                        id='stepper-linear-validation-role'
                      >
                        {roles.map((role, index) => (
                          <MenuItem key={index} value={role}>
                            {role}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    )}
                  />
                  {accountErrors.role && <FormHelperText error>Role is a required field</FormHelperText>}
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel error={Boolean(accountErrors.branchCode)}>Branch Code</InputLabel>
                  <Controller
                    name='branchCode'
                    control={accountControl}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <Select label='Branch Code' {...field} error={Boolean(accountErrors.branchCode)}>
                        {branchCodes.map(branchCode => (
                          <MenuItem key={branchCode} value={branchCode}>
                            {branchCode}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    )}
                  />
                  {accountErrors.branchCode && <FormHelperText error>Branch Code is a required field</FormHelperText>}
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} className='flex justify-between'>
                <Button variant='outlined' disabled color='secondary'>
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button variant='contained' type='submit'>
                  Next
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        )
      case 1:
        return (
          <form key={1} onSubmit={handlePersonalSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Grid container spacing={5}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography className='font-medium' color='text.primary'>
                  {steps[1].title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant='body2'>{steps[1].subtitle}</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='firstName'
                  control={personalControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      fullWidth
                      label='First Name'
                      placeholder='John'
                      {...(personalErrors.firstName && {
                        error: true,
                        helperText: personalErrors.firstName.message
                      })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='lastName'
                  control={personalControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      fullWidth
                      label='Last Name'
                      placeholder='Doe'
                      {...(personalErrors.lastName && {
                        error: true,
                        helperText: personalErrors.lastName.message
                      })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel error={Boolean(personalErrors.country)}>Country</InputLabel>
                  <Controller
                    name='country'
                    control={personalControl}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <Select label='Country' {...field} error={Boolean(personalErrors.country)}>
                        <MenuItem value='UK'>UK</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value='USA'>USA</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value='Australia'>Australia</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value='Germany'>Germany</MenuItem>
                      </Select>
                    )}
                  />
                  {personalErrors.country && <FormHelperText error>country is a required field</FormHelperText>}
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel error={Boolean(personalErrors.language)}>Language</InputLabel>
                  <Controller
                    name='language'
                    control={personalControl}
                    rules={{ required: true }}
                    render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                      <Select
                        multiple
                        label='Language'
                        value={Array.isArray(value) ? value : []}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        error={Boolean(personalErrors.language)}
                      >
                        {Languages.map(language => (
                          <MenuItem key={language} value={language}>
                            {language}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    )}
                  />
                  {personalErrors.language && <FormHelperText error>language is a required field</FormHelperText>}
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} className='flex justify-between'>
                <Button variant='outlined' onClick={handleBack} color='secondary'>
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button variant='contained' type='submit' onClick={() => setOpenPreviewModal(!openPreviewModal)}>
                  Next
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        )
      case 2:
        return (
          <form key={2} onSubmit={handleSocialSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Grid container spacing={5}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography className='font-medium' color='text.primary'>
                  {steps[2].title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant='body2'>{steps[2].subtitle}</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='twitter'
                  control={socialControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                    <TextField
                      value={value}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      fullWidth
                      label='Twitter'
                      placeholder='https://twitter.com/johndoe'
                      {...(socialErrors.twitter && { error: true, helperText: socialErrors.twitter.message })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='facebook'
                  control={socialControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                    <TextField
                      value={value}
                      onChange={onChange}
                      fullWidth
                      label='Facebook'
                      placeholder='https://facebook.com/johndoe'
                      {...(socialErrors.facebook && { error: true, helperText: socialErrors.facebook.message })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='google'
                  control={socialControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      fullWidth
                      label='Google'
                      placeholder='https://google.com/johndoe'
                      {...(socialErrors.google && { error: true, helperText: socialErrors.google.message })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Controller
                  name='linkedIn'
                  control={socialControl}
                  rules={{ required: true }}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...field}
                      fullWidth
                      label='LinkedIn'
                      placeholder='https://linkedin.com/johndoe'
                      {...(socialErrors.linkedIn && { error: true, helperText: socialErrors.linkedIn.message })}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} className='flex justify-between'>
                <Button variant='outlined' onClick={handleBack} color='secondary'>
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button variant='contained' type='submit'>
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        )
      default:
        return <Typography color='text.primary'>Unknown stepIndex</Typography>
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <CardContent>
          <StepperWrapper>
            <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
              {steps.map((label, index) => {
                const labelProps: {
                  error?: boolean
                } = {}

                if (index === activeStep) {
                  labelProps.error = false

                  if (
                    (accountErrors.email || accountErrors.username || accountErrors.role || accountErrors.branchCode) &&
                    activeStep === 0
                  ) {
                    labelProps.error = true
                  } else if (
                    (personalErrors.firstName ||
                      personalErrors.lastName ||
                      personalErrors.country ||
                      personalErrors.language) &&
                    activeStep === 1
                  ) {
                    labelProps.error = true
                  } else if (
                    (socialErrors.google || socialErrors.twitter || socialErrors.facebook || socialErrors.linkedIn) &&
                    activeStep === 2
                  ) {
                    labelProps.error = true
                  } else {
                    labelProps.error = false
                  }
                }

                return (
                  <Step key={index}>
                    <StepLabel {...labelProps} StepIconComponent={StepperCustomDot}>
                      <div className='step-label'>
                        <Typography className='step-number' color='text.primary'>{`0${index + 1}`}</Typography>
                        <div>
                          <Typography className='step-title' color='text.primary'>
                            {label.title}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography className='step-subtitle' color='text.primary'>
                            {label.subtitle}
                          </Typography>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </StepLabel>
                  </Step>
                )
              })}
            </Stepper>
          </StepperWrapper>
        </CardContent>
        <Divider />
        <CardContent>
          {activeStep === steps.length ? (
            <>
              <Typography className='mlb-2 mli-1' color='text.primary'>
                All steps are completed!
              </Typography>
              <div className='flex justify-end mt-4'>
                <Button variant='contained' onClick={handleReset}>
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </div>
            </>
          ) : (
            renderStepContent(activeStep)
          )}
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      <PreviewModal open={openPreviewModal} setOpen={setOpenPreviewModal} formData={formData} />
    </>
  )
}

export default StepperLinearWithValidation

preview modal component:
'use client'
import React from 'react'

import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogActions } from '@mui/material'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'

type AccountFormData = {
  username: string
  department: string
  role: string
  branchCode: string
}

type PersonalFormData = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  country: string
  language: string[]
}

type FormData = {
  account: AccountFormData
  personal: PersonalFormData
}

type PreviewModalProps = {
  open: boolean
  setOpen: (open: boolean) => void
  formData: {
    account: {
      username: ''
      department: ''
      role: ''
      branchCode: ''
    }
    personal: {
      firstName: ''
      lastName: ''
      country: ''
      language: []
    }
  }
}

const PreviewModal: React.FC<PreviewModalProps> = ({ open, setOpen, formData }) => {
  // Check if formData is null or undefined
  if (!formData) {
    return null // or display an error message
  }

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} maxWidth='md' fullWidth>
      <DialogTitle>Preview Modal</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {console.log('account:', formData.account)}
          {console.log('personal:', formData.personal)}
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant='subtitle1'>User Details</Typography>
            {formData.account ? (
              <div>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Username: {formData.account.username}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Department: {formData.account.department}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Role: {formData.account.role}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Branch Code: {formData.account.branchCode}</Typography>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <Typography variant='body1'>No account data available.</Typography>
            )}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant='subtitle1'>Personal Info</Typography>
            {formData.personal && formData.personal.language ? (
              <div>
                <Typography variant='body1'>First Name: {formData.personal.firstName}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Last Name: {formData.personal.lastName}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Country: {formData.personal.country}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body1'>Languages: {formData.personal.language.join(', ')}</Typography>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <Typography variant='body1'>No personal data available.</Typography>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button variant='contained' onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
          Close
        </Button>

---

      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  )
}

export default PreviewModal


I have tried several ways to have data values captured in the multi-forms to show on the modal/dialog but it keeps showing in the preview modal component as undefined when called up on the preview modal. Result:
on the console:
account: undefined index.tsx:57
personal: undefined index.tsx:58
Preview Modal
User Details
No account data available.
Personal Info
No personal data available.
